# TypeScript 'An export assignment cannot be used in a module with other exported elements'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, node-modules

My Objective is to have a single redis.js file for all redis operation from all over my code just like below snippet

```
const Redis = require('./handler/redis.js');
Redis.set();
Redis.get() etc ..

from my app.js
require('./core/redis')(redisClient);
```

Above code runs without any error But i am getting typescript error as **'An export assignment cannot be used in a module with other exported elements'**

```
module.exports = function(redisClient) {

redisClient.on('error',function(err) {
    console.log('Redis Error ' + err);
});

redisClient.on('connected',function() {
    console.log('Redis Connected');
});

module.exports.set = function(key, value, next) {
    redisClient.set(key,value,next);
};

module.exports.get = function(key, next) {
    redisClient.get(key,next);
};

module.exports.del = function(key, next) {
    redisClient.del(key,next);
};
};
```

Even with this warning how my code is running

EDITED CODE :
    //from my app.js
    require('./core/redis').init(redisClient);

```
module.exports.init = function(redisClient) {
   redisClient = redisClient;
}

redisClient.on('error',function(err) {
    console.log('Redis Error ' + err);
});

redisClient.on('connected',function() {
    console.log('Redis Connected');
});

module.exports.set = function(key, value, next) {
    redisClient.set(key,value,next);
};

module.exports.get = function(key, next) {
    redisClient.get(key,next);
};

module.exports.del = function(key, next) {
    redisClient.del(key,next);
};
```

Is this the correct way to do it

Comment: Your module has an export assignment and other exported elements.

Comment: @DaveNewton i am not able to understand what you are trying to say here, can you help me with some links or explain to me in detail

Comment: You have an `exports =`. You have `exports.foo =‘. The first is an export assignment. The rest are other exported elements.

Comment: @DaveNewton What should be changed ? As stated above i want to maintain a single file for all ops, or shall i leave it like that bcoz my code runs properly

Answer (score 1):

You have written `module.exports = function(redisClient) {` as assignment statement for `exports` from this module and after that that you overriding this statement with  `module.exports.set`, `module.exports.get` and `module.exports.del` That's why it is giving error **'An export assignment cannot be used in a module with other exported elements'**. I don't know from where you are getting the `redisClient` parameter to the function. If this is already available in this current module then you can simply write the code as

```
redisClient.on('error',function(err) {
    console.log('Redis Error ' + err);
});

redisClient.on('connected',function() {
    console.log('Redis Connected');
});

module.exports.set = function(key, value, next) {
    redisClient.set(key,value,next);
};

module.exports.get = function(key, next) {
    redisClient.get(key,next);
};

module.exports.del = function(key, next) {
    redisClient.del(key,next);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the issue, but i am actually sending the redisClient from a different file! I also wonder is it working than !